# proof-verification

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Let $f: X \to X$ be a function
with $f_n = f \circ\ f \circ\ f ...$ ($n$ times) prove that if there is a $n \in \mathbb{N_0}$ with: for all $x \in X$: $f_n(x) = x$ than $f$ is a bijection.

Supose $f$ isn't a bijection than because $\vert X \vert = \vert X \vert $,  $f$ also isn't a surjection so $\vert X \vert > \vert f(X) \vert$ en in general $\vert X \vert > \vert f_n(X) \vert$ so we can say that for all $n \in \mathbb{N_0}$ there exists an $x \in X$: $f_n(x) = \emptyset$ and because of this also $f_n(x) \neq x$ this a contradiction with the defention of $f$ so $f$ must be a bijection.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Maybe easier would be to note that if $f_n=Id_X$ for some $n$, then $f\circ f_{n-1}=f_{n-1}\circ f=Id_X$, meaning $f$ is invertible and hence a bijection.

Comment: If $X$ is infinite then "not a bijection" does not imply "not a surjection". Also saying $f$ is not a surjection does not imply $|X|>|f(X)|$. I can't figure out where that $f_n(x)=\emptyset$ comes from.

Comment: Please use a more descriptive title!

Comment: "$n\in \Bbb N_0$" makes me wonder what function $f_0$ is supposed to be. The only sensible possibility would be that $f_0= Id_X$. but that would mean $n=0$ always  meets your condition regardless of the function $f$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair in Belgium we use $\Bbb N_0$ so that $n = {1,2,3,4,...}$ but I know that in the Netherlands it means ${0,1,2,3 ..}$  so I understand the confusion.

Comment: Well, I am in the USA, but that does seem a confusing notation. Why would you put a subscript of $0$ to indicate $0$ is *not* included? It seems to me that $\Bbb N_1$ or $\Bbb N_+$ would be more natural. I grew up with the US's "New Math" curricula, where $\Bbb N$ was $1$ and on, $\Bbb W$ was $0$ and on. But I quickly learned as an adult that the "whole numbers" language was an invention of the US Education dept, and unknown elsewhere, and eventually that $0 \in \Bbb N$ had been a common definition all along. So I guess I cannot be too critical of other countries.